# Code working on jsfiddle.net doesn't work locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, jsfiddle

I'd like to play around locally with [this code I found](https://jsfiddle.net/cscottnet/ceshcL3u/presentation/). To present it quickly, the code reproduce the front end of a wikipedia page in a minimalistic fashion.
I tried the code in Brackets, without any modification except the basic tags (<html>, <script>,<body>) and the linking of the jquery library in the same version than the mini wiki code, here is the code I use :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>  
        <title> example</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <h1 id="title">MiniWiki</h1>
        <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            var titleElem = document.getElementById('title');
            var contentElem = document.getElementById('content');
            var stylesheetElem = document.getElementById('style');
            function extractTitle(title) {
                return title.replace(/(^.\/)|(#.*$)/g, '').replace(/_/g, ' ');
            }
            function loadPage(title) {
                var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org:443/api/rest_v1/page/html/' + encodeURIComponent(title);
                return $.ajax(url).then(function (data) {
                    var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
                    // Use mediawiki content stylesheet
                    $(stylesheetElem).remove();
                    stylesheetElem = doc.querySelector('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');
                    $('head').append(stylesheetElem);
                    // Update title and content
                    $(titleElem).text(doc.title.replace(/^User:Cscott\//, '').replace(/_/g, ' '));
                    var $content = $(contentElem).empty();
                    Array.from(doc.body.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
                        $content.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
                    });
                    $content.append(Array.from(doc.body.children));
                    // Handle redirects
                    $('link[rel="mw:PageProp/redirect"]').replaceWith(function() {
                        return $('<a rel="mw:WikiLink">REDIRECT</a>').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
                    });
                    // Add click handler to wiki links
                    $('a[rel="mw:WikiLink"]', $content).click(function (e) {
                        var newTitle = extractTitle($(e.currentTarget).attr('href'));
                        History.pushState(null, newTitle, "?title="+encodeURIComponent(newTitle));
                        return false; // Don't use normal href handler
                    });
                });
            }
            // Make the back button work
            History.replaceState(null, '', ''); // Ensure a state change later
            $(window).on('statechange', function() {
                loadPage(History.getState().title);
            });
            // Load the start page
            History.replaceState(null, 'User:Cscott/MiniWiki', '');
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

When trying this code, I keep having the following error in the console :

> mini-wiki.html:51 Uncaught TypeError: History.replaceState is not a
> function

I noticed that by replacing **History.replaceState**, by **history.replaceState**, I could get rid of the error, but then, I have no errors left in the console and only the <h1> content is displayed.

Is there any reasons why this code is working flawlessly on jsfiddle.net and not locally ?

Comment: Look in the 'Resources' section of the left panel in the fiddle. There are several libraries you did not include in your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to remove the `jquery.history.js` file and replace it with the `jquery` that you're importing in your script tag and it throws the error you're mentioning.

I think you need to include the `jquery.history.js` file, that was included in the jsfiddle.

I would recommend that you try importing the following line into your head tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history.js/1.8/bundled-uncompressed/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, I tried to add this line and all the other ressources as you can see in the EDIT section of my post but with no further success

Answer (score 1):

using the answers given above, I made it work by linking the missing scripts and css, and I have the expected result now, here's the full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>  
        <title> example</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
       
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.32.2/es6-shim.min.js"> </script>
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history.js/1.8/bundled-uncompressed/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"> </script>
        
    </head>

    
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <h1 id="title">MiniWiki</h1>
        <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            var titleElem = document.getElementById('title');
            var contentElem = document.getElementById('content');
            var stylesheetElem = document.getElementById('style');
            function extractTitle(title) {
                return title.replace(/(^.\/)|(#.*$)/g, '').replace(/_/g, ' ');
            }
            function loadPage(title) {
                var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org:443/api/rest_v1/page/html/' + encodeURIComponent(title);
                return $.ajax(url).then(function (data) {
                    var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
                    // Use mediawiki content stylesheet
                    $(stylesheetElem).remove();
                    stylesheetElem = doc.querySelector('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');
                    $('head').append(stylesheetElem);
                    // Update title and content
                    $(titleElem).text(doc.title.replace(/^User:Cscott\//, '').replace(/_/g, ' '));
                    var $content = $(contentElem).empty();
                    Array.from(doc.body.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
                        $content.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
                    });
                    $content.append(Array.from(doc.body.children));
                    // Handle redirects
                    $('link[rel="mw:PageProp/redirect"]').replaceWith(function() {
                        return $('<a rel="mw:WikiLink">REDIRECT</a>').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
                    });
                    // Add click handler to wiki links
                    $('a[rel="mw:WikiLink"]', $content).click(function (e) {
                        var newTitle = extractTitle($(e.currentTarget).attr('href'));
                        History.pushState(null, newTitle, "?title="+encodeURIComponent(newTitle));
                        return false; // Don't use normal href handler
                    });
                });
            }
            // Make the back button work
            History.replaceState(null, '', ''); // Ensure a state change later
            $(window).on('statechange', function() {
                loadPage(History.getState().title);
            });
            // Load the start page
            History.replaceState(null, 'User:Cscott/MiniWiki', '');
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```